# Whenever Gem's Reboot Task Not Being Run in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

This is my first time using the 'whenever' gem in rails, and I cannot get it to work.
I followed the documentation and added this to my GEMFILE:

`gem 'whenever', :require => false`

Then I ran bundle install and typed `wheneverize` and edited  `config/schedule.rb` which includes the following lines:

```
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
# siteA.rake and siteB.rake are in in /lib/tasks/
every :reboot do
    rake "scrape_data:siteA" , :environment => :development
    rake "scrape_data:siteB" , :environment => :development
end
```

Then I typed in `whenever --update-crontab myAppName` which gave the output `[write] crontab file updated`. Now when I run my rails server, both these custom rake tasks don't run.

Comment: Have you tried actually rebooting your machine?

Comment: Tried that now, still no luck

Comment: I can run rake scrape_data:siteA and rake scrape_data:siteB but I cannot schedule them to run automatically